# how to switch camera source in kurento?

Tags: webrtc, kurento, media-source

I am trying to add an option of camera switch in video call handled by [KMS (Kurento media server)](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/index.html) and I am digging throw a lot to their documentation and other sources but I find nothing useful

```
var options = {
    localVideo: videoInput,
    remoteVideo: videoOutput,
    onicecandidate: onIceCandidate,
    mediaConstraints: {
        audio: isAudio || call_settings.isAudio,
        video: isVideo || call_settings.isVideo

    }

}
webRtcPeer = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options, function (
```

this is my code which is connecting throw peer and all media permission is handled by kurento itself so that I am not able to change the source of media location.

and i am not sure how to do it with kurento any kind of help is appreciable thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass custom `mediaConstraints` to the options or create stream by yourself and send it as `videoStream` in the options and skip `mediaConstraints` as mentioned in kurento utils js docs.

For switching device / getting stream based on device, please refer below sample

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

You can refer below doc for `videoStream` usage

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/kurento_utils_js.html

Comment: i read the doc but i am not sure how to switch the stream URL in an ongoing call and i also did not found any example on doc also can please help me with this

Comment: ok i got you.... you wanted me to add the video stream in options but still i am not sure how to it in a running call

Comment: can you show me  how to update videoStream parameter while call is running

Comment: You can't update `videoStream` once it's created. But you can create a new `WebRtcPeer` connection for screenshare and connect other `WebRTCPeerConnection` for screen share and make user's subscribe to this `WebRTCPeerConnection` also.

Comment: but then it increases the load on my server